# Hiding keyboard in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, keyboard

I am having a fragment and in that fragment there is an add button which triggers a dialog when clicked . In that dialog I am having two edittext and two buttons. On click of save button dialog is dismissed. Now problem is that when I click on save button edit text keyboard closes and another keyboard pop up.(Edit text keyboard type is number while that popup after is alphabetical).I want to close this keyboard therefore I tried configChanges and this method

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Context ctx) {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    // check if no view has focus:
    View v = ((Activity) ctx).getCurrentFocus();
    if (v == null)
        return;

    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

But none of this method works and I am also not having any edit text in fragment from which dialog appears.

dialog.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lin_add_dns">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="ADD DNS"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/add_dns_title"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/txt_add_dns"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="DNS NAME"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/et_name"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColorHint="#999999"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:hint="IP Address"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/et_ip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:digits="0123456789."
        android:textColorHint="#999999"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_click"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/btn_submit"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ccc"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/TopHeader"
                        android:text="Current WIFI Info"
                        android:paddingRight="15dp"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:baselineAligned="false">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".50"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textAlignment="gravity"
                        android:id="@+id/WiFiConnectLeft"
                        android:text="Wifi Name :"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textAlignment="gravity"
                        android:id="@+id/DefaultGatewayLeft"
                        android:text="Default Gateway :"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textAlignment="gravity"
                        android:id="@+id/DNS1Left"
                        android:text="Primary DNS :"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textAlignment="gravity"
                        android:id="@+id/DNS2Left"
                        android:text="Secondary DNS :"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textAlignment="gravity"
                        android:id="@+id/CurrentIPLeft"
                        android:text="IP Address :"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".50"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:id="@+id/WiFiConnectedText"
                        android:textAlignment="gravity"
                        android:text=""/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/DefaultGatewayText"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/DNS1Text"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/DNS2Text"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/CurrentIPText"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

                -<TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="CHANGE DNS"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:id="@+id/MiddleHeaderText"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/lin_primary"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="15dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/primary"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:id="@+id/PrimaryDNSText"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:textSize="13sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.2"
                    android:background="#000"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:maxLength="16"
                    android:id="@+id/EDITDNS1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text=""/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.8"
                    android:text="BROWSE"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_click"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:id="@+id/BrowseDNS1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lin_primary"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/lin_secondary"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="15dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/secondary"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:id="@+id/SecondaryDNSText"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.2"
                    android:background="#000"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:maxLength="16"
                    android:id="@+id/EDITDNS2"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text=""
                    />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.8"
                    android:text="BROWSE"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_click"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:id="@+id/BrowseDNS2"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="3">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:text="ADD DNS"
                    android:id="@+id/btn_add"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_click"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/UpdateDNS"
                    android:text="Update"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_click"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/ResetWifi"
                    android:text="RESET"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_click"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Dialog java code

```
addDns.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder;
                    final android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog alertDialog;
                    TextView txt_add_dns;
                    Button btn_submit;
                    final EditText et_name, et_dns;
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                    final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_dns_dialog, (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lin_add_dns));
                    builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
                    builder.setView(layout);
                    alertDialog = builder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                    alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.dialog_bg);
                    txt_add_dns = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txt_add_dns);
                    et_name = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.et_name);
                    et_dns = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.et_ip);
                    Fonts.setHelveticaFont(ctx, txt_add_dns);
                    btn_submit = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
                    Fonts.setHelveticaFont(ctx, btn_submit);
                    InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
                    filters[0] = new InputFilter() {
                        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                            if (end > start) {
                                String destTxt = dest.toString();
                                String resultingTxt = destTxt.substring(0, dstart) + source.subSequence(start, end) + destTxt.substring(dend);
                                if (!resultingTxt.matches("^\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3})?)?)?)?)?)?")) {
                                    return "";
                                } else {
                                    String[] splits = resultingTxt.split("\\.");
                                    for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
                                        if (Integer.valueOf(splits[i]) > 255) {
                                            return "";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            return null;
                        }
                    };
                    et_dns.setFilters(filters);
                    btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Fonts.setHelveticaFont(ctx, et_name);
                            Fonts.setHelveticaFont(ctx, et_dns);
                            et_dns.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

                            if (!et_name.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !et_dns.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                                String name = et_name.getText().toString();
                                String dns = et_dns.getText().toString();
                                IPAddressValidator iptester = new IPAddressValidator();

                                boolean valid = iptester.validate(dns);
                                if (valid) {
                                    dataBaseHelper.addUserDns(name, dns);
                                   // dnsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                                    hideKeyboard(getActivity());

                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Invalid IP Address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Please enter IP Address and DNS Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }


                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

What's the issue here??

**EDIT:**After checking for each edit text individually I found that the keyboard from first editext didn't closes itself.So I added focus change listener and when it loses focus I called hide Keyboard.
I debugged line by line and everything works perfectly, debugger also enters hide keyboard method but that code is not able to hide keyboard. Is there any other method for hiding keyboard in fragments??
Is this problem with context that is passed in hide keyboard method ??Can we get context of an alert dialog in android because when I debug it showing context of Main Activity as I am passing getActivity() as parameter .Is this the issue??

Comment: Have you tried `InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY` instead of `0` as parameter?

Comment: this also doesn't work

Comment: why would I hide keyboard on touch??I am hiding it on submit button click

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

create this methos infragment and call this method where u want to hide keyboard in your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding Keyboard using method doesn't work for me. I added the code directly in submit button and that worked for me. Here is what I added

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                                    im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et_name.getWindowToken(), 0);
                                    InputMethodManager im1 = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                                    im1.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et_dns.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Here et_dns and et_name are my edit text